# Trying to create associative array but keep getting numeric

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I am trying to create an associate array like this

```
while($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {

        $user = $row['first_name'] ."_" . $row['last_name'];
        $userholder[$user] = $row['choice'];
        $event = $row['event_name'] . "_" . $row['event_location'] . "_" . $row['even_date'];
        $consolidateEvents[$event] = $userholder;
    }
```

but my `$consolidateEvents` array is numeric. I cannot see what I am doing wrong. Why am I not getting `$event` as the key for my array?

Comment: what is result of echo $event ? this can not be complete code, something is fishy other than your code.

Comment: The result of echo $event is Practice_Cross Flats Over 50_2017-02-07 19:22:00

Comment: and what is print_r($consolidateEvents)

Comment: No it is not the complete code but I was trying show just the relevant code I can post everything if it helps?

Comment: Because, from this snippet of your code, no problem, I see, its working properly, that why I am asking, for other code

Comment: print_r($consolidateEvents) is Array ( [0] => Array ( [Rodger_P] => Yes [Jayne_Lynch] => Yes [Bugs_Bunny] => Yes ) )

I would expect 

Array ( [Practice_Cross Flats Over 50_2017-02-07 19:22:00] => Array ( [Rodger_P] => Yes [Jayne_Lynch] => Yes [Bugs_Bunny] => Yes ) )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135496/discussion-between-rahul-m-and-clint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to correct your output,

```
function custom_function($input_array){
    $output_array = array();
    foreach ($input_array as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($v as $k => $v) {
            $output_array[$key][$k] = $v;
        }
    }
    return $output_array;
}
```

Give it a try, this will work

Comment: Works brilliantly. Thanks a bunch